# ui-router without executing controller on every route change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ui-router sample configuration:

```
header: {
      templateUrl: 'header.tpl',
      controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
},
sidebar: {
      templateUrl: 'sidebar.tpl',
      controller: 'SidebarCtrl'
},
main: {
    templateUrl: 'main.tpl'
}
```

The website starts with a login page which only has a `main` view.
All the other pages in the app require authentication.

Problem:
Every time I open a new route, HeaderCtrl and SidebarCtrl are being executed.

Is there a way to make the SidebarCtrl and HeaderCtrl not re-execute on every route change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can achieve this by implemented nested state. In case of nested state, parent state - controller, directives are executed only once and on change in child state will not execute them again until and unless you want to forcibly execute them.

With nested state just add a parent state let us say "app" with a template which will act as container having header and footer controller - please see these can be directives as well. And a content container having ui-view.

Child states will be like "app.child1", "app.child2", etc.

Please note child state has to start with "app.", because this is the link which defines the parent child relationship w.r.t. ui-router.

In case you are using named views, then updated the child state like this where main is the name/label of view.

```
views: { 'main@': 'settings.tpl' }
```

This design will make sure your header and footer controllers are not executed on every state change.

Comment: Will the header and footer controller be inherited as well? or should I define them again?

Comment: Yes they will be inherited on all the child states.

Comment: Can you please update your answer and mention that we need to reference the `main` template via `main@` or else it won't work

Comment: We need to reference the main state not the template. I will update. Thanks for update

Comment: Yes but in order to update the `main` template, we have to reference it using `main@`

Comment: When you define a child state, say `app.settings`, assuming you want to use the same header and sidebar templates but only change the main template, you'd have to write this: `views: { 'main@': 'settings.tpl' }`

Comment: Ok ok. Now i get it. You are talking about named views. I will update